# Gemfire start pulse error - Running desktop applications is not supported on Linux

Tags: gemfire

I have installed GemFire 9.0.3 in a UNIX "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)" environment.

I am unable to start the pulse here. Please help, with other alternatives! ( Reference - http://gemfire90.docs.pivotal.io/gemfire/getting_started/15_minute_quickstart_gfsh.html)

[bin]# ./gfsh
    _________________________     __
   / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
  / /  **/ /_**  /_____  / _____  /
 / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /
/______/_/      /______/*/    /*/

9.0.3

Monitor and Manage Pivotal GemFire

gfsh>start pulse
Running desktop applications is not supported on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the start pulse command does is launch a browser pointing at the url for pulse. So you can just go to the pulse url yourself in your browser:

http://[your_locator_host]:7070/pulse/

Comment: Is there a way to enable swagger UI? Should I be enabling it in locator level ?

Comment: I think you need to enable it on each server you start using --start-rest-api=true.

https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/latest/rest_apps/using_swagger.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Gemfire GUI (open source at https://github.com/ldom22/GGGUI)